# Embed Python in C: unable to read python return integer value

Tags: python, c, embed, cross-language

I am trying to embed python in my `C` code. So the objective is that I want to run a python code inside `C` program, and when the python code finish running, it should return a integer value back to my C program.

In my python code "try.py", I specify `return 10` at the end of the python file.

However, I tried the following, but the return value is always `0`. Why?

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{    int sys;
     Py_Initialize();
     PyObject* PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString("try.py", "r");
     sys=PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), "try.py", 1);
     Py_Finalize();
     printf("\n\n the return value is %d\n\n",sys);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has to be because `PyRun_SimpleFileEx` returns `0` on success, think about it, a python program returning an integer that way doesn't make sens, Please post the `python` code too. [Read this](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags)

Comment: You say "_I specify `return 10` at the end of the python file._" Don't you get a `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` there?

Answer (score 0):

The `PyRun_SimpleFileEx` returns `0` on success and `-1` on error.

This was extracted from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleStringFlags)

> `int PyRun_SimpleStringFlags(const char *command, PyCompilerFlags *flags)`
>
> Executes the Python source code from command in the **main** module according to the flags argument. If **main** does not already exist, it is created. Returns 0 on success or -1 if an exception was raised. If there was an error, there is no way to get the exception information. For the meaning of flags, see below.
>
> Note that if an otherwise unhandled SystemExit is raised, this function will not return -1, but exit the process, as long as Py_InspectFlag is not set.